# Extend a LoopbackJS endpoint method

Tags: loopbackjs

I'd like to extend the user login POST method in loopback.

So far I have extended the base user class to roll out my own, however how do I add functionality to a particular endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example I've created a new model called "UserAuth2" which extended the existing User model provided by LoopbackJS. I've created the model using the `slc loopback:model` tool.

In order to extend a function in Loopback use the following code within your model's JS file :

```
module.exports = function(UserAuth2) {
   // Get reference to endpoint
   var previousImplementation = UserAuth2.login;

   // Create new implementation of endpoint
   UserAuth2.login = function(){

   //Get existing implementation
   /*** arguments is an array of existing arguments that the login 
      function takes***/

   previousImplementation.apply(this, arguments);

   //Extend the method and do something else here
   console.log("New functionality");
   }
}
```